# Android ORMLite

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using ormlite for android 4.47.
All is good, but sometimes when run application I receive exception with next cause:

```
you must call initialize() before you can use the dao
```

In my Application class I'm init ormlite like write in are doc.

```
DatabaseFactory.setHelper(applicationContext);
```

What is going on ?
This exception I receive not often. Maybe one in a day.

Full stack:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: you must call initialize() before you can use the dao
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.checkForInitialized(BaseDaoImpl.java:925)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryBuilder(BaseDaoImpl.java:247)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseForeignCollection.getPreparedQuery(BaseForeignCollection.java:174)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.EagerForeignCollection.<init>(EagerForeignCollection.java:38)
            at com.j256.ormlite.field.FieldType.buildForeignCollection(FieldType.java:784)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.mapped.BaseMappedQuery.mapRow(BaseMappedQuery.java:82)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.getCurrent(SelectIterator.java:270)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.nextThrow(SelectIterator.java:161)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.query(StatementExecutor.java:200)
            at com.j256.ormlite.stmt.StatementExecutor.queryForAll(StatementExecutor.java:118)
            at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.queryForAll(BaseDaoImpl.java:239)
            at com.ls.dailysteals.core.database.dao.HeistDAO.getAllHeist(HeistDAO.java:31)
            at com.ls.dailysteals.ui.fragment.HeistFragment$1.doInBackground(HeistFragment.java:92)
            at com.ls.dailysteals.ui.fragment.HeistFragment$1.doInBackground(HeistFragment.java:88)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Init:

```
    public class DSApplication extends Application {

        private static Context applicationContext;

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            DatabaseFactory.setHelper(applicationContext);
    }
}
```

First call:
Called in fragment lifecyrcle method onViewCreated(...);

```
databaseTask = new AsyncTask<Object, List<ShortDeal>, List<ShortDeal>>() {

            @Override
            protected List<ShortDeal> doInBackground(Object... params) {
                return DatabaseFactory.getHelper().getShortDealDAO().getAllShortDeal();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<ShortDeal> shortDeals) {
                super.onPostExecute(shortDeals);
                updateAdapter(shortDeals);
            }
        };

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            databaseTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        } else {
            databaseTask.execute();
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a race condition. The exception is triggered from a background thread. My guess, without seeing your initialization code, is that you are initializing the DAO on the main thread and trying to access in the background. Every so often the access occurs before the initialization: race condition.

Comment: what I can to do ? I need object of dao class in background thread ?

Comment: Show the code where you are initializing ORMLite. Show where the background thread is started.

Comment: post edited, see in top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used ORMLite, but mt guess this is because your applicationContext is always null, thus it thinks it's not initalized

```
public class DSApplication extends Application {

    private static Context applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        applicationContext = this;
        DatabaseFactory.setHelper(this);
    }
    ....
```

Comment: This is wrong, because I receive error very rarely. Not always. But I try using this, thank for your answer.

Comment: Maybe you've got DatabaseFactory.setHelper(context) call somewhere else too and in most conditions it is being called before other operation so it works?

Comment: No, this is excluded! I have one call DatabaseFactory.setHelper(context); in my Application class!

Comment: @smail2133 one in your Application class or one in your entire project?

Comment: This is not correct.  THis is a race condition between threads.

Comment: @Gray Do you have any hint to avoid this race condition?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
YourDao dao = new YourDao(OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getConnectionSource(), YourDao.class);

public class YourDao extends BaseDaoImpl<YourClass, Integer> {    
    protected YourDao(ConnectionSource connectionSource, Class<YourClass> dataClass) throws SQLException {
        super(connectionSource, dataClass);
    }
}
```

instead

```
Dao<YourClass, Integer> yourDao = OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.getDao(YourClass.class);
```

Before call YourDao.queryBuilder()

Constructor of BaseDaoImpl call initialize()